# Navigation corrupted - ViewModel can't close?

Tags: xamarin.ios, navigation, viewmodel, mvvmcross

On every other place the navigation just works fine, only on this place it doesnt work (it's set up like all the other Viewmodels)

I'm trying to navigate from ImportView (ImportViewModel) to the LoginView (LoginViewModel). 
On Buttonclick (Binded MvxCommand in ViewModel) I'm calling `ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>();`

Its working but afterwards the whole navigation is broken. If I move now from the newly opened LoginViewModel to for Example TestViewModel (or TestView), and now going "Back", I'm not coming to the LoginView back, instead to a BlackScreen and there is one more "Back", after that the App crashes... (`MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Can't add self as subview`)

Where is here the Problem?

Here some Debuginformations:

```
[0:] mvx:Warning: 26.41 Don't know how to close this viewmodel - topmost view does not present this viewmodel
[0:] 
2013-12-13 13:19:28.400 INMobileAdminUIiOS[6932:60b] mvx:Diagnostic: 26.81 Showing ViewModel LoginViewModel
[0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 26.81 Showing ViewModel LoginViewModel
[0:] 
2013-12-13 13:19:28.799 INMobileAdminUIiOS[6932:60b] TouchNavigation:Diagnostic: 27.21 Navigate requested
[0:] TouchNavigation:Diagnostic: 27.21 Navigate requested
2013-12-13 13:19:29.085 INMobileAdminUIiOS[6932:60b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
[0:] 
2013-12-13 13:19:29.224 INMobileAdminUIiOS[6932:601f] 13.12.2013 13:19:29   TinyMessage: ProgressDialogDismissMessage
[0:] 13.12.2013 13:19:29    TinyMessage: ProgressDialogDismissMessage
2013-12-13 13:19:29.463 INMobileAdminUIiOS[6932:60b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

Comment: maybe show the code - e.g. a simple app which reproduces the problem. There are a lot of hits on here about nested push animations - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nested+push+animation

Comment: I built a simple app, but wasn't able to reproduce the problem. But I did fix it somehow, look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I added `this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);` in `viewDidAppear`

The problem happens when the view controller tries to pop to top view controller without waiting for the loading end of child view controller. `popToRootViewControllerAnimated()` must be called after the view appears!

Answer (score -2):

I have solved the problem.

I added

```
this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
```

in `viewDidAppear`